# How to Delete ForeignKey (Cascade Delete)

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, .net-6.0, cascading-deletes, ef-core-6.0

I have two model which are bound to each other with foreign key constraints.

1. `PurchaseOrder` is the parent table
2. `PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown` is the child table

Now the problem is when I am trying to delete the parent table, this error occurs:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_POQtyBreakDown_PurchaseOrder_PurchaseOrderPoId". The conflict occurred in database "InfoSys_CommercialAPI", table "dbo.POQtyBreakDown", column 'PurchaseOrderPoId'

I have tried the followed the following method for implementing the `Cascade Delete`. But it's not working properly.

`DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Commercial Tables
    // Back-To-Back
    public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown> POQtyBreakDown { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown>()
            .HasOne(s => s.PurchaseOrder)
            .WithMany(b => b.PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.PurchaseOrderPoId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

`PurchaseOrder` & `PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown` model classes are shown here:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int PoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("CONTRACT")]
    public int? ContractListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContractListId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public ContractList? ContractList { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ORDER NO")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public string? OrderNo { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown> PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown { get; set; } = new List<PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown>();
}

public class PurchaseOrderQtyBreakDown
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? PurchaseOrderPoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PurchaseOrderPoId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public PurchaseOrder? PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    public int? ContractListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContractListId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public ContractList? ContractList { get; set; }

    public int? Qty { get; set; }

    public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public string? OrderNo { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The FK in the database should als have a Cascade specification. If you use migrations, add and apply a new migration.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from Microsoft Documentation . You just need to do the following actions :

1. Go to the Database
2. Select The Child Table
3. Open Keys
4. Select the FK Relation which you want to "Cascade"
5. Right click and select modify
6. Select INSERT And UPDATE Spec
7. Select Delete Rule
8. Set the option "Cascade"
9. And Save.

From now you can delete the Parent Rows.